Why would a cache clear be required every time we visit one site before we can visit a subdomain of that site?
We have multiple sites, hosted on different platforms.
The first site is our main corporate website with a url like https://www.website.com
This site is a Wordpress site hosted with GoDaddy. It was recently updated with a new design.
The second site is our an internal accounting website, located at http://accounts.website.com
This is an internal tool to our company written in ASP.NET
For some reason once we visit the main corporate website (https://www.website.com) we are unable to visit the accounting site (http://accounts.website.com) until we clear the cache. When we try to access the accounting site we get a browser error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"
Any ideas about what could cause this and how I could solve or diagnose it?
We expect each site to load when we visit them.
Pings and traces to each URL return the correct IP address so DNS appears correct. We have tried looking into the cache contents to see if we can find something that is a problem but were not able to find anything understandable.
